# SQL Pivot group by rows to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

So I have a table for activities of drivers that I want to calculate per day.
Example data:

| Name | StartDateAndTime | EndDateAndTime | StartText | EndText | WorkState |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jim | 2021-09-09 06:28:16 | 2021-09-09 07:28:16 | "StartPlace0" | "EndPlace0" | "Pause" |
| Jim | 2021-09-09 07:28:16 | 2021-09-09 08:28:16 | "StartPlace1" | "EndPlace1" | "Loading" |
| Jim | 2021-09-09 08:28:16 | 2021-09-09 09:28:16 | "StartPlace2" | "EndPlace2" | "Driving" |
| Jim | 2021-09-09 10:28:16 | 2021-09-09 11:28:16 | "StartPlace4" | "EndPlace4" | "Loading" |
| Jim | 2021-10-09 09:28:16 | 2021-10-09 10:28:16 | "StartPlace5" | "EndPlace5" | "Driving" |
| Jim | 2021-10-09 10:28:16 | 2021-10-09 11:28:16 | "StartPlace6" | "EndPlace6" | "Loading" |
| Jim | 2021-10-09 11:28:16 | 2021-10-09 14:28:16 | "StartPlace7" | "EndPlace7" | "Driving" |

Desired output: (I have only 3 possible WorkStates)

| Name | StartDateAndTime | EndDateAndTime | StartText | EndText | Loading | Driving |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jim | 2021-09-09 06:28:16 | 2021-09-09 11:28:16 | "StartPlace0" | "EndPlace4" | 00:02:00 | 00:01:00 |
| Jim | 2021-10-09 09:28:16 | 2021-09-09 14:28:16 | "StartPlace5" | "EndPlace7" | 00:01:00 | 00:04:00 |

| Pause | DayPerformed |
| --- | --- |
| 00:01:00 | 2021-09-09 |
| 00:00:00 | 2021-10-09 |

What I have so far in my view : (a summary)

```
 --CREATE view vwWorkingTimesPerDay as
select  
   w.DriverName, 
   convert(date, w.StartDateAndTime) as DayPerformed,
   MIN(w.StartDateAndTime) as StartTime,
   MAX(w.EndDateAndTime) as EndTime,
   StartPositionText,
   EndPositionText

from  ( 
  SELECT *,
  StartPositionText = FIRST_VALUE(StartPosText) OVER (PARTITION BY w.DriverName, convert(date, 
  w.StartDateAndTime)
        ORDER BY w.StartDateAndTime ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING),
  EndPositionText   = LAST_VALUE(EndPosText) OVER (PARTITION BY w.DriverName, convert(date, 
  w.StartDateAndTime)
        ORDER BY w.StartDateAndTime ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
FROM webfleet.tblWorkingTimes w) w

  group by w.DriverName, 
     convert(date, w.StartDateAndTime),
     StartPositionText,
     EndPositionText,
```

To show the durations in the original table I used:

```
right('00' + convert(varchar, datepart(hour, dateadd(s, sum(datediff(second, 
    w.StartDateAndTime, w.EndDateAndTime)), 0))), 2) + ':'
 + right('00' + convert(varchar, datepart(minute, dateadd(s, sum(datediff(second, 
  w.StartDateAndTime, w.EndDateAndTime)), 0))), 2) + ':'
  + right('00' + convert(varchar, datepart(second, dateadd(s, sum(datediff(second, 
  w.StartDateAndTime, w.EndDateAndTime)), 0))), 2) 
   as Duration
```

I tried this article [https://www.sqlshack.com/multiple-options-to-transposing-rows-into-columns](https://www.sqlshack.com/multiple-options-to-transposing-rows-into-columns/)

But I am not experienced enough to get it to work with those options.
The order of data that I desired is not important and if there is a better way to calculate and display the Duration I am happy to hear it.

Comment: Can you explain the logic: do you want to just calculate alternating sets of `Loading``Driving``Pause`? Or do you want to sum up the total per day?

Comment: Per workstate i want to calculate how many hours they spend on it per day so we know how much we have to pay them. (per month is the next challenge) The problem is the company that sends me the data doesn't have a summary per day so I have to calculate it myself.

Comment: Also sorry for late reply we don't work in the weekends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will take a few steps

- We use `CAST AS date` to get the date without the time
- `ROW_NUMBER` and `LEAD` help us identify the beginning and end of each grouping
- Then simply aggregate by `Name` and the date
- And use conditional aggregation to get the results we want
- To get a time value, we add number of seconds to `0:00:00` time

```sql
SELECT
  Name,
  DayPerformed,
  StartDateAndTime = MIN(StartDateAndTime),
  EndDateAndTime = MAX(EndDateAndTime),
  StartText = MIN(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN StartText END),
  EndText = MIN(CASE WHEN nxt IS NULL THEN EndText END),
  Loading = DATEADD(ms,
      ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN WorkState = 'Loading' THEN DATEDIFF(ms, StartDateAndTime, EndDateAndTime) END), 0),
      CAST('0:00:00' AS time)),
  Driving = DATEADD(ms, 
      ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN WorkState = 'Driving' THEN DATEDIFF(ms, StartDateAndTime, EndDateAndTime) END), 0),
      CAST('0:00:00' AS time)),
  Pause   = DATEADD(ms,
      ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN WorkState = 'Pause'   THEN DATEDIFF(ms, StartDateAndTime, EndDateAndTime) END), 0), 
      CAST('0:00:00' AS time))
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name, DayPerformed ORDER BY StartDateAndTime),
      nxt = LEAD(WorkState) OVER (PARTITION BY Name, DayPerformed ORDER BY StartDateAndTime)
    FROM tblWorkingTimes wt
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES (CAST(StartDateAndTime AS date))) v(DayPerformed)
) wt
GROUP BY
  Name,
  DayPerformed;
```

To aggregate by month simply replace `DayPerformed` with

```
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (EOMONTH(StartDateAndTime))) v(DayPerformed)
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c7fdb4e60d3ee29d5a65d534679fa2e2)

Comment: TY for taking the time to answer! Works perfect. Also thanks for explaining a bit. Really helps to learn more about SQL.